# Error when importing Dialogflow in Python

Tags: python, bots, dialogflow-es

I downloaded a project in which dialogflow is used, from a repo. However, it showed an error on my pycharm "run". The error itself says

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'quiniela.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it.
```

But I have had that error show on my pycharm even when the error has nothing to do with it. For instance, if I make an integer variable and try to print it, it would show that exact error, which clearly isn't it, the error would be not casting the integer and trying to print it. So, what I'm saying is, that error appears when ANY error exists, so I usually ignore it and that's my problem to fix later, but that's not this question.

I tracked the error, and found that whenever I comment the line  `import dialogflow` (and every line that uses dialogflow) in my views.py, the error disappears. If I uncomment just that `import dialogflow`, again it fails. Why would that be? If I go to interpreter settings, I see that the package dialogflow is installed, and if I try to install it, it says it's already installed, so that is not the problem.

Why do you think it could fail to import dialogflow? The dialogflow version is 0.7.2, and the python version is 3.6, and I'm using Windows 10.